# How do I make my bot send a command to make a separate bot do something?

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.js

So I'm fairly new to coding with JavaScript, specifically discord.js. I have a bot called Icarus installed on my Discord server which is capable of making a vocal countdown in a voice channel.

I'm trying to make a bot that can automatically activate the command for Icarus to do that every now and again.

I can get my bot to send the message

```
'!cd 10'
```

Which will start the countdown for the voice channel the sender is currently in for 10 seconds.

My bot is in the channel, but when it sends that message, nothing happens.

I believe this is because the owner of Icarus has put an If-statement in their code that prevents bots from activating commands.

Does anyone know a workaround for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only work around would be to tell that bot owner to allow either all bot inputs or make an exception for your own.

There is no way for you to externally affect how another bot runs in that fashion.